# Burn cd audio with wmlib.dll without gabs in c# or vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, audio

Good nights, I need the help the one who could. I burn a CD in format Audio with an object IWMPCdromBurn, nevertheless, between track and track stops two seconds of silence, which goes against what I need: I need that it reproduces without gaps, so that there is listened quite followed (Track At Once). If someone knows the solution it would do a good favor to myself... Later I leave my code

```
Private WithEvents player As New WindowsMediaPlayer()
Private Grabador As IWMPCdromBurn
Private listaGrabación As IWMPPlaylist = player.newPlaylist("plyList", "")

Grabador.burnPlaylist = listaGrabación
Grabador.burnFormat = WMPBurnFormat.wmpbfAudioCD
player.settings.autoStart = False
player.currentPlaylist = Grabador.burnPlaylist
Grabador.refreshStatus()

Grabador = CType(player.cdromCollection.getByDriveSpecifier(Me.cmbUnidades.SelectedItem), IWMPCdromBurn)

Grabador.startBurn()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you need "disc-at-once" IWMPCdromBurn does not support that, sorry :-(

> To do so-called "gapless audio", you must use a Disc-At-Once (DAO) recording method.  The IDiscFormat2RawCD allows you to use different variations of DAO recording, however it requires a properly formatted stream.
>
> Currently, IMAPIv2 does not support creating streams for this kind of audio disc.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50f0d35b-7e6c-4deb-9c33-cfb76107c625/how-to-burn-audio-cd-using-disc-at-once?forum=windowsopticalplatform

Comment: Thanks you very muchos for your attention!